# Rails f.label in radio buttons and checkboxes without label text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, label

This is somewhat of a confusing question, I want the labels in my form to be just the `for` value in my form, but when the form it's generated in HTML the text is appended to the `for`, for example:

I have:

```
<%= label :dates, 'Tomorrow' %>
```

I want:

```
<label for="dates">Tomorrow</label>
```

what happens is:

```
<label for="dates_Tomorrow">Tomorrow</label>
```

This same thing happens with the checkboxes, the reason I want the HTML to be generated like this is because I want to get the label value from each of my fields, so I can use jquery to display the label text somewhere else

for that I plan to use this:

```
$( function(){
    $('.when :input').change(function() {
      var idVal = $(this).attr("id");

      $('.to_find a').html($("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text());
    });
});
```

Am I using the right approach to get the labels out of my forms or is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do in this line `$('.to_find a').html($("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text());`? BTW that is how Rails generates labels!

Comment: Yes, that's to change the text of the link in the element with class `to_find`   to the label of whatever idVal field is, it's something I found on other answers related on how to get the label of a field. Really? on the [label Api dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label) the label seems to come out clean of the text, am I missing something?

Comment: You want to display "tomorrow" somewhere else, or the `for` value?

Comment: I don't understand. "You write in your header: Rails f.label in radio buttons and checkboxes without label text?"

But underneath you write: I want `<label for="dates">Tomorrow</label>`

Isn't that text?

Comment: I want to display whatever the label of the selected radio button is.

the problem is that the `for` value gets the first word inside the label appended, so instead of just `for = "dates"` I get `for = "dates_Tomorrow"` which according to the documentation shouldn't happen.

Comment: Try `label_tag :dates, 'Tomorrow'`

Comment: Yeah that worked, but I just realized what I really needed is kinda the opposite, changing the value of the label to match the one of the value in the radio, still I think this is some useful info to know.